# Multi-architectural binary rpm and the noarch

Tags: linux, packaging, rpm, rpmbuild

I have two (32-bit and 64-bit) versions of a compiled software which I would like to package into ONE binary RPM. I am wondering if 'noarch' *target* is suitable for this purpose or there are better alternatives? The only issue with 'noarch' that I see is that having i386 and x86_64 binaries in the package doesn't make it architecture-independent which 'noarch' is supposed to be used for.

Comment: Are these binaries to be used on the host that has the RPM installed on it? Or are they helper binaries used by the main application in the RPM on remote hosts/etc. as appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to have one binary RPM supporting two architectures. You have to generate 2 RPMs. As you say, the .noarch is for architecture independent RPMs, such a scripts, which can be run on any architecture.

I guess you could build one RPM containing the two binaries (with different names), but this probably goes against the packaging guidelines, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Do you happen to know how is it possible to produce `noarch` and e.g. `i686` packages using one spec? When I specify `BuildArch: noarch` for the subpackage, all packages are assigned to `noarch`.