# RPM gives a warning during un-installation if file does not exist

Tags: rpm, suse, rpm-spec, rhel7

Some files of my rpm package (depending on some conditions) are deleted in **%post** scriptlet which causes a warning during the uninstallation: *"remove failed: No such file or directory"*

*Note:* The problem does not occur in systems with older versions of RPM and is noticed only on RHEL7 and SLES12.

While trying to figure this out, I found the following code in RPM sources (fsm.c):

```
    /*
     * Missing %ghost or %missingok entries are not errors.
     * XXX: Are non-existent files ever an actual error here? Afterall
     * that's exactly what we're trying to accomplish here,
     * and complaining about job already done seems like kinderkarten
     * level "But it was MY turn!" whining...
     */
    if (rc == RPMERR_ENOENT && missingok) {
    rc = 0;
    }

    /*
     * Dont whine on non-empty directories for now. We might be able
     * to track at least some of the expected failures though,
     * such as when we knowingly left config file backups etc behind.
     */
    if (rc == RPMERR_ENOTEMPTY) {
    rc = 0;
    }

    if (rc) {
    int lvl = strict_erasures ? RPMLOG_ERR : RPMLOG_WARNING;
    rpmlog(lvl, _("%s %s: remove failed: %s\n"),
        S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode) ? _("directory") : _("file"),
        fpath, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
```

Seems the **%missingok** *virtual file attribute* solves the problem, but
actually, there is no **%missingok** attribute, there is the **%config(missingok)** one, instead.

What makes this look strange to me is that we mark the file as **config** file, though AFAICS there is no strict difference between config files and ordinary files.

The question: Is it OK to use the abovementioned attribute for non-config files (for binaries)? Will this cause problems on upgrades or something?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say for certain but I believe it is fine though it will have the side-effect of listing that file as a config file and getting the `.rpmsave` behavior for modified files I believe (but that shouldn't matter much). That being said you can probably just ignore the warning (like the comment indicates it isn't really an issue). My question though is why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: To @EtanReisner:
I decided to combine binaries of x86 and x86_64 architectures into one package (the corresponding question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502523/multi-architectural-binary-rpm-and-the-noarch) and remove one of them depending on host's architecture. Another option is to use the FatElf, but I don't want my binary to be so fat :). Yet another workaround is the create that files in %preun scriptlet and let the rpm delete them.

Comment: Ah, I recall the question now. You never answered my comment (though I forget why I asked it now). =) Anyway, I think this is a poor way to package the binaries but that is neither here nor there. I would probably do one of two things. Just stop deleting the wrong binaries (they don't really hurt anything being there). Or `%ghost` symlinks to the appropriate binaries for the system and keep the real binaries in arch-tagged directories and create the symlinks in `%post` (and stop deleting the wrong binaries). =)

Comment: If you don't want the warning, `rm -rf FILENAME 2>/dev/null || true` should do it.